# Is there any API to add path.repo configuration to already running ElasticSearch Instances?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have single node Elasticsearch instance that has been running from about a month now. I need to start backing it up. But the backup-restore API need an entry in the elasticsearch.yml. I need to restart the ES to make it reflect that change. Is there any alternative to it? Is there anyway i can make an entry or pass the backup location as a parameter to the API so that i can run without restarting the ES instance?

Comment: No, you need to restart it in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Any settings update in path, path.repo or path.logs requires a whole cluster restart to apply those changes.